# Updating ASPNetUsers primary key data type from nvarchar to bigint using code first migration in .Net Core (.Net 5)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

Here's my ApplicationDbContext.cs code that adds other fields to ASPNetUsers table. I noticed that the Identity generated tables in the database set the primary key, Id, as nvarchar (450). How will I change ASPNetUsers' Id to bigint (Int64) via code first migration approach?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string SAPNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why change the pk of the users table to `int`? The interesting part of using `Guid`s for primary key on the users/roles table is that they are random, and cannot be guessed that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiAswkgmiYk&list=PL4LFuHwItvKZ6Mz5W5wzD9uo3w6tNChhX&index=6&ab_channel=GavinLon) related to EF Core Migrations and was able to apply it in my codes.

1 - I changed ApplicationUser class in ApplicationDbContext.cs from `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Int64>` so that PK will update to bigint in database. You can set it to int if you want the PK to be int only in database.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Int64>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string SAPNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
}
```

2 - I added ApplicationRole class in ApplicationDbContext.cs that inherits IdentityRole. Left it empty

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Int64>
{
}
```

3 - I changed the IdentityDbContext class in ApplicationDbContext.cs from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` to `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole, Int64>`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole, Int64>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Here's the whole code of ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Int64>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string SAPNo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Int64 DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Int64>
{
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole, Int64>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override it with the new keyword. I'm not sure if it will work, but I assume EF Core will use the new ID as the primary key

```
public class IdentityUser
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
      public new long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Tried to migrate this and update in the database but nothing changed